# Opening normal.dotm user form from document based on template

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a user form called MetadataForm in my normal.dotm template which is used to collect some custom  metadata. It's set to show when a new document is created like this:

```
Public Sub AutoNew()
Dim meta_form As Normal.MetadataForm
Set meta_form = New Normal.MetadataForm
meta_form.Show
End Sub
```

It works nicely when I create a new document directly from normal.dotm, but when I create a new document based on any other template I get an error "Object variable or With block variable not set".

Comment: And which line of code triggers the error?

Comment: And is the code shown also in Normal.dotm, or another file?